# What happens if you add the attribute "com.apple.icloud.desktop" to just a random folder that lives in your home folder?

Tags: icloud, finder, extended-attributes

Will it start to behave just like `Desktop` and `Documents`? Or will it break iCloud drive?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is one of those cases where you have to try it out to see what happens. I doubt it is officially documented anywhere what would happen.

From my experience what would happen is that Finder would start treating the folder slightly different. I.e. for the ordinary Desktop folder, this attribute is mainly used to signal to Finder that it should display the Desktop folder as part of the iCloud Drive instead of as a "free-standing", ordinary folder.

It should not break iCloud Drive, nor will it start synchronising the folder similarly to the Desktop and Documents folders.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried it. Nothing happened. Then I ran `killall Finder`, still nothing changed. Then I rebooted, still nothing changed. Oh well...

Comment: What did you want it to do?

Comment: Isn't this just a comment of confirmation to jksoegaard's answer?

Comment: @WGroleau I wish it would treat the new folder exactly like Desktop and Documents. That it would sync it with iCloud while the folders in some ways still look like native folders. Now I solved it by just adding the folder to the iCloud drive folder, but then I had to make a symbolic link to my Home folder and that just looks a bit more ugly to me.

Comment: @agarza, almost, but my experience is not exactly the same as jksoegaard's. The folder did not get treated differently in any way. Also not in appearance, which jksoegaard did seem to say.